# TeamCity Visual Studio plugin forgetting credentials

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity

Does anyone else have a problem where everytime you need to commit using the TeamCity VS plugin, you have to re-enter the TeamCity server address and credentials?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So should anyone stumble across this again - simple answer is to upgrade to the latest version! Worked for us.