# Visual Studio TeamCity plugin never remembers password, despite ticking "remember password" box

Tags: visual-studio, teamcity, visual-studio-2022

I have just updated Visual Studio professional 2022 from 17.5.2 to 17.5.5. This was the first thing I tried when attempting to fix this mildly annoying bug.

Every time I open VS I am prompted to enter my teamcity password (it remembers my username), regardless of whether or not I ticked the box previously. [image atttached](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110653/teamcity-visual-studio-plugin-forgetting-credentials)

I can find only [one other reference](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1110653/teamcity-visual-studio-plugin-forgetting-credentials) to this problem, but it's unsolved and from 13 years ago.

Thanks